# open windows share in Nautilus Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: networking, nautilus, samba, 19.04

I'm having this strange problem that I can not open any folder on a windows server in our network from Nautilus.
And also the location(s) will not mount.

But when I connect in the terminal with smbclient I can access these locations without any problems.

I have tried purging and reinstalling samba samba-common etc.

What else can I try to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to create the mount by using the mount -av options to see what error messages I would get.

this line is now working for me.

```
    //server.domain.com/users$/username /media/foldername cifs auto,vers=1.0,credentials=/home/<username>.smbcredentials,noexec,iocharset=utf8,uid=1001,gid=27,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide enough information to answer the question so I am going to guess. The assumptions I will use for this guess are:

** Your Windows machine has SMB1 disabled on the server side.

** You are trying to access the shares through "discovery": Nautilus > Other Locations > Windows Network > Host > Shares.

It's a bug in the way gvfsd-smb-browse operates:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/1778322?comments=all

https://bugs.launchpad.net/gvfs/+bug/1828107

There is no way around this issue at the moment but not being able to connect to the share via "discovery" does not mean you cannot access the share at all. You just have to do it by naming the host specifically in Nautilus:

smb://hostname/share

smb://ip-address/share

*OR if you are running Windows 10 and have enabled mDNS through its firewall by its "mDNS hostname"*

smb://hostname.local/share

Comment: i'm sorry
I don't know the version of SMB on the windows server in our network.
And no, I can not connect when I do smb://hostname or smb://ipaddress

but as I've said, when I use smbclient in the terminal I can connect and list the contents without any problem.
So, to me, that means my credentials are correct, the share I'm trying to connect to is correct, but somehow, somewhere, I can't connect in nautilus.